# WRONG VERSION in log: INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate

I'm having problems regarding hibernate version jar loading....eclipse log says I'm using 3.2.4.sp1 but in my pom.xml I'm using 4.2.0.Final. So I suppose this is why I'm getting the exception...

```
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [root-context.xml]
    INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
    INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [root-context.xml]
    INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
    INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'jdbcTemplate': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]]
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]]
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'sessionFactory': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]]
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]]
    INFO : org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@8916a2: startup date [Sun Jan 19 17:55:32 BRST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e58cb8: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,employeeDao,managerDao,taskDao,timesheetDao,entityGenerator,cartService,timesheetService,jdbcTemplate,dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
    INFO : org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1
    INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
    INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : cglib
    INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
    INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e58cb8: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,employeeDao,managerDao,taskDao,timesheetDao,entityGenerator,cartService,timesheetService,jdbcTemplate,dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
    ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1554d32] to prepare test instance [bch.com.br.test.dao.EmployeeDaoTest@13f136e]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    ...
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:163)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:198)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:348)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
        ... 52 more
```

pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <org.hibernate-version>4.2.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- View -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>          

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>MySpringMVCCart</warName>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments</outputDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you have included another version of Spring in your projects build path?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried cleaning the project in eclipse? (Project>Clean...)
2. You can also try removing /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.m2/repository/org/hibernate folder. During the next run of mvn you will see in terminal that hibernate will download dependencies for hiibernate - try observing when 3.2.4.sp1 is being downloaded.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another Eclipse project added to your project's build path?
I had a similar issue and it turned out that:

- I had added another Eclipse project that was using the troublesome version of Hibernate
- Since Maven isn't tracking that other project (it wasn't in my pom.xml, just directly added to the build path), both versions of Hibernate were making their way to the classpath
- The JVM (for reasons that I don't understand) picked the version of Hibernate from the inner project

So try removing the wrong version of Hibernate from the other project or just build and release it so that Maven can track its dependencies for you in the pom.